# When using XSLT upon XML import, is there anyway to pass the name of the InDesign template to the XSLT?

Tags: xslt, adobe-indesign

I am importing XML files into InDesign and applying an XSLT transform during import. I need a way to pass to the XSLT the name of the InDesign template that is calling it. Here's what I'm trying to do:

My source XML contains tables with relative column widths – which InDesign does not support. From what I understand, table column widths must be identified as pts for InDesign to accurately maintain table column width sizes. Therefore, I am attempting to use XSLT to convert the table widths from relative widths to point sizes.

This is simple when you know the width of the text column in the InDesign template as you can calculate the width of the table columns in the XML by percentages of the text column width in the InDesign template. However, I have multiple templates that all have different text column widths, and the same XSLT will be used with all of them. So I need to be able to create a variable that is filled at the time of import. To accomplish this, we want to create an XML-based config file that lists each template and the text column width for that template.

I know how to write all the XSLT to accomplish this, but what I don't know is how to determine which template the XSLT is being called from upon import. Once I know this information, I can look up the value I need for the calculation from the config file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i don't think it can be done - XML import in InDesign does not accept parameters. I would use a script to call a correct XSLT depending on a template

Comment: instead of using the same xslt for all templates, create XSLTs for each template. Those XSLTs can include the main XSLT and define the template specific parameters

Comment: @NicolaiKant If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting using a script to import the XML to call the desired XSLT by passing the template name to the script. This is more effort than we anticipated. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user1754036 Thanks! I like the simplicity of this solution, and this is what I'm going to recommend.